Mock Google's StorageClient ListObjects method using Moq
I'm trying to unit test the following method
public List<string> GetFilesInGCS(string bucket, string node)
{
    List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        log.Info($"Getting files from {bucket}...");
        foreach (var storageObject in storageClient.ListObjects(bucket, node))
            fileNames.Add(storageObject.Name);

        log.Info($"Total files: {fileNames.Count}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Task.Run(async () => { await _emailer.SendErrorAsync(ex); });
        log.Error(ex);
    }
    return fileNames;
}

The problem is I don't know how to properly mock the return for the ListObjects method. It returns an abstract class of PageEnumerable<Objects, Object>.
This is what I have so far.
[Test]
public void TestGetFilesInGCS()
{
    Mock<StorageClient> storageClientMock = new Mock<StorageClient>(MockBehavior.Loose);
    storageClientMock.Setup(m => m.ListObjects(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<ListObjectsOptions>()));
    GoogleService g = new GoogleService(storageClientMock.Object);
    var files = g.GetFilesInGCS("test", "test");
    Assert.That(files, Is.Not.Empty);
}


If the return type of ListObjects is PageEnumerable<Objects, Object>, and that's an abstract class, you can use Moq to create an instance of that as well:
var res = new Mock<PageEnumerable<Objects, Object>>()

and then set up storageClientMock to return it:
storageClientMock
    .Setup(m => m.ListObjects(
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<ListObjectsOptions>()))
    .Returns(res.Object);

That's the general idea, anyway.
